# random time WIN DEATH: in cocos2d-x

Tags: android, visual-c++, android-ndk, cocos2d-x

I developed a game with cocos2d-x. I tried to compile it under android. The first three scenes are good - but when I added the last functional, the application begins to close at random times and in random scenes.

Here is the relevant log:

```
04-18 15:30:54.404: I/DEBUG: * *
04-18 15:30:54.404: I/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'lge/thunderg/thunderg:2.3.3/GRI40/LG-P500-V20c.19C1E59AC2:user/ota-rel-keys,release-keys'
04-18 15:30:54.404: I/DEBUG: >>> com.mobiap.casino <<<
04-18 15:30:54.404: I/DEBUG: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000000
04-18 15:30:54.404: I/DEBUG: r0 ffffffff r1 73746000 r2 00000004 r3 ffff0ff0
04-18 15:30:54.414: I/DEBUG: r4 00000000 r5 73746000 r6 afd46470 r7 00000000
04-18 15:30:54.414: I/DEBUG: r8 aca4a965 r9 00098450 10 00100000 fp 00000001
04-18 15:30:54.414: I/DEBUG: ip afd24579 sp 100ffe28 lr afd24571 pc aca652c2 cpsr 80000030
04-18 15:30:54.414: I/DEBUG: d0 400000003eaaaaab d1 3ff0000041f00000
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d2 bfd3441350baf6de d3 c1493000c1323800
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d4 4900000040f7b000 d5 000000000007bd80
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d6 4515a00000000800 d7 40800000c48ee000
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d8 0000000000000000 d9 0000000000000000
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d10 0000000000000000 d11 0000000000000000
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d12 0000000000000000 d13 0000000000000000
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: d14 0000000000000000 d15 0000000000000000
04-18 15:30:54.424: I/DEBUG: scr 80000012
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: #00 pc 000652c2 /system/lib/libdvm.so
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: #01 lr afd24571 /system/lib/libc.so
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: code around pc:
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: aca652a0 000267ab 4b09b570 0b0d1c14 0b1018c2 
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: aca652b0 032d0300 d20742a8 1c291a2d f7ac2204 
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: aca652c0 6820eaf8 60211941 46c0bd70 00000fff 
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: aca652d0 4b10b5f8 447b1c01 6d066818 d0162900 
04-18 15:30:54.534: I/DEBUG: aca652e0 23001c02 e00b251c 42a16ad4 1c2cd306 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: code around lr:
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: afd24550 ffffff8c 00028e2e 0000076c 2301b510 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: afd24560 fdd0f7ff 46c0bd10 1c04b510 fd36f7ed 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: afd24570 20016004 bd104240 1c03b510 db0233ff 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: afd24580 f7ff4240 bd10fff1 4d1bb5f0 4f1c4b1b 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: afd24590 58ea447d 880359ec 88278811 1c0eb087 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: stack:
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffde8 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffdec 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffdf0 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffdf4 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffdf8 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffdfc 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe00 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe04 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe08 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe0c 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe10 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe14 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.544: I/DEBUG: 100ffe18 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe1c afd24587 /system/lib/libc.so
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe20 df002777 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe24 e3a070ad 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: #00 100ffe28 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe2c 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe30 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe34 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe38 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe3c 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe40 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe44 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe48 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe4c 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe50 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe54 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe58 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe5c 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe60 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe64 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe68 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.554: I/DEBUG: 100ffe6c 00000000 
04-18 15:30:54.674: I/DEBUG: debuggerd committing suicide to free the zombie!
04-18 15:30:54.674: I/BootReceiver(1568): Copying /data/tombstones/tombstone_02 to DropBox (SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE)
04-18 15:30:54.704: I/DEBUG: debuggerd: Jun 27 2011 23:27:49
04-18 15:30:54.754: D/StatusBarPolicy(1649): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 2
04-18 15:30:54.754: D/StatusBarPolicy(1649): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=25020 curHPLMN=25020
04-18 15:30:54.834: I/ActivityManager(1568): Process com.mobiap.casino (pid 1051) has died.
04-18 15:30:54.854: E/InputDispatcher(1568): channel '407d93b0 com.mobiap.casino/com.mobiap.casino.android_casino (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred. events=0x8
04-18 15:30:54.854: E/InputDispatcher(1568): channel '407d93b0 com.mobiap.casino/com.mobiap.casino.android_casino (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-18 15:30:54.854: I/WindowManager(1568): WIN DEATH: Window{407d93b0 com.mobiap.casino/com.mobiap.casino.android_casino paused=false}
04-18 15:30:54.904: I/WindowManager(1568): WIN DEATH: Window{407e4130 SurfaceView paused=false}
04-18 15:30:54.924: I/WindowManager(1568): Setting rotation to 0, animFlags=1
04-18 15:30:54.924: I/ActivityManager(1568): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=250/20 loc=ru_RU touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=1/1 orien=1 layout=18 uiMode=17 seq=606}
```

I tried all versions of ndk and cocos2d-x. I tried to reduce graphics. I tried to find memory leaks by ddms, but i didn't see anything suspicious.

Could it be that cause of the problem is CCUserDefaults call? Or using of `CCTextureCache::sharedTextureCache()->addImageAsync("Slots/KNOPKI_UPR/PAYT_light.png",this,callfuncO_selector(HelloWorld::LoadImageCash));`?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this error in my cocos2dx game. The worst thing is that the debug mode didn't tell me anything. Then I start to cut some methods to find the cause of my problem. I found this:

```
char positionx[10]= {0};
sprintf(positionx, "X->%f",m_playerLayer->getPosition().x);
CCLOG(positionx);
```

My problem was in the size of my array of `char`. I commented this and the error stopped.
The curious thing is that in Xcode it's not a problem, just in Android.